# Trying to run Kile gives a segmentation fault on Linux Mint 19

Tags: linux-mint, kde, segmentation-fault, kile

With the latest version of Kile installed, trying to run it crashes with a segmentation fault:

```
$ kile
qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/16/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/16@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/16/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/16@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/22/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/22@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/24/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/24@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/24/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/24@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/32/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/32@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/32/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/32@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/48/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/48@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/48/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/48@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/64/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/64@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/64/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/64@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/96/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/96@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/128/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/128@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/256/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/256@2x/"
Invalid Context= "Apps" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/apps/symbolic/"
Invalid Context= "Mimetypes" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Mint-Y/mimetypes/symbolic/"
kf5.kio.core: Refilling KProtocolInfoFactory cache in the hope to find "mtp"
kf5.kservice.services: KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType "ThumbCreator" not found
No text-to-speech plug-ins were found.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How can Kile be run in Linux Mint 19?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After much searching, I found the answer in a [Debian bug post](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=887088) exchange:

> If the okular package is not installed, kile can not start and crashes
>   on a segmentation fault.

The solution was to run

```
sudo apt-get install okular
```

Answer (score 0):

In had similar error in Ubuntu 18.04 and I used one of these workarounds.

1. kile works if launched from Activities but not in the terminal.
2. remove Qt5 libs from LD_Library_Path e.g. in .bashrc